# Какие именно алгоритмы и в каких случаях используются в веб-разработке?

Tags: веб-программирование, алгоритм

Не скажу, что я большой профессионал в веб-разработке, но некоторый опыт имеется. Часто слышу о необходимости знать алгоритмы, но кроме рекурсии я пока ни с чем из алгоритмов не сталкивался. Так какие алгоритмы нужно знать веб-разработчику и где в вебе они применяются?

Comment: Мне кажется, рекурсия -- это не алгоритм, это инструмент для реализации алгоритмов.

Comment: Возможно, но она подробно рассматривается в "Структуре и интерпретации компьютерных программ", потому так и поставил вопрос

Comment: хм... может "кто-то" имеет ввиду не "алгоритмы", а "шаблоны проектирования" ?

Comment: нет, именно алгоритмы - сортировки, двоичные деревья итд.

Comment: Отличный пример того случая, когда нужно знать алгоритмы, чтобы не писать кривые велосипеды:

http://hashcode.ru/questions/181199/c-усовершенствование-random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует огромный список алгоритмов, начиная от поиска НОД и заканчивая распознаванием образов и криптографией. Вот вам очень небольшой список, содранный с c2.com/wiki:

- Алгоритм поиска A*
- Двоичный поиск
- Метод ветвей и границ
- Сортировка (много алгоритмов)
- Алгоритм Дейкстры
- Дискретное преобразование Фурье
- Алгоритмы честного распределения
- Максимизация матожидания
- Метод Гаусса
- Поиск висящей вершины в орграфе
- Алгортимы поиска подстроки
- SoundEx
- Поиск циклов (пара указателей)
- Рандеву

Comment: Хорошо, но вопрос был в другом - практическое применение алгоритмов в веб-разработке. Я и так знаю, что алгоритмов существует много

Comment: @Олег Серебряков: а причём тут именно веб-разработка? Ваш код на сервере выполняет какую-то задачу, для этой задачи могут понадобиться алгоритмы, в зависимости от задачи. Например, поиск глаз на картинке. Это не зависит от того, вы пишете код для сервера (аватарки) или для desktop-приложения (обработка фотографий).

Comment: Ок, по ходу я понял - в веб-разработке, как и в разработке любого ПО, все зависит от конкретной задачи - если она тривиальная, то алгоритмы могут быть не нужны в принципе, но если нестандартная, то скорее всего понадобятся. Спасибо

Comment: @Олег Серебряков: очень хорошо сформулировано!

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, бывают тривиальные задачи, требующие тривиальных алгоритмов:) Пример - самый обыкновенный бинарный поиск в отсортированном массиве из 1000000 элементов быстрее прямого перебора где-то в 10000 раз.